# Easy way to select more than one field using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Take a look of this sample object,

```
public class Demo
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public int Code1 { get; set; }

    public int Code2 { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and lets say I want to put all codes (`Code1`, `Code2`) in one list (`IEnumerable`)... one way is this one:

```
var codes = demoList.Select(item => item.Code1).ToList();
codes.AddRange(demoList.Select(item => item.Code2));
//var uniqueCodes = codes.Distinct(); // optional
```

I know this is not a nice neither optimal solution, so I am curious to know what will be a better approach / (best practice)?

Comment: There's no way (without reflection) to select all properties automatically. So you need to select every property manually as shown by [Ani](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21483884/284240). You should consider to use a `List<int> Codes` as property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Linq** is **not** a **silver bullet** to kill everything

For your intent i'd propose the following

```
var codes = new List<int>(demoList.Count * 2);
foreach(var demo in demoList)
{
  codes.Add(demo.Code1);
  codes.Add(demo.Code2);
}
```

**BENCHMARK**

I did a benchmark iterating a list of 1 million and 1 thousand instances with my solution and Ani's

> Amount: 1 million
>
> Mine : 2ms
>
> Ani's: 20ms
>
> Amount 1000 items
>
> Mine : 1ms
>
> Ani's: 12ms

the sample code

```
        List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>(1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new MyClass
            {
                Code1 = i,
                Code2 = i * 2,
            });
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer1 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var resultLinq = list.SelectMany(item => new[] { item.Code1, item.Code2 }).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Ani's: {0}", timer1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var codes = new List<int>(list.Count * 2);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            codes.Add(item.Code1);
            codes.Add(item.Code2);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Mine : {0}", timer2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, why not. Clear as day and doesn't create intermediate result objects.

Comment: And you are able to initialize your codes list with the correct size upfront

Answer (score 6):

How about with `SelectMany`:

```
var codes = demoList.SelectMany(item => new[] { item.Code1, item.Code2 });
```

By the way, the idiomatic way of doing a concatenation in LINQ is with `Concat`:

```
var codes = demoList.Select(item => item.Code1)          
                    .Concat(demoList.Select(item => item.Code2));
```

Comment: Why create an array and then perform a SelectMany when it's not needed? Seems overkill...

Comment: @Jason Well, this solution works, unlike yours.  If you have an easier way *to produce the desired results*, then by all means, share it.

Answer (score 2):

```
// this won't return duplicates so no need to use Distinct.
var codes = demoList.Select(i=> i.Code1)
                    .Union(demoList.Select(i=>i.Code2));
```

Edited just for completeness (see @Ani answer) after some comments:

```
// Optionally use .Distinct()
var codes = demoList.Select(i=>i.Code1)
                    .Concat(demoList.Select(i=>i.Code2))
                    .Distinct();
```

Comment: This will remove all duplicates, which is not a part of the requirements.  You're looking for `Concat`, not `Union`.

Comment: @Sevy you are right! I think this will works if he wants to (distinct) from what the OP asked as optional. So it's a one way to go without doing Concat and Distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Even the code you have written is perfect,i am just giving you another option
Try this

```
var output = Enumerable.Concat(demoList.Select(item => item.Code1).ToList(), demoList.Select(item => item.Code2).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Luis' answer is good enough for me. but I did re-factored it, using extension methods for any numbers of fields... and the optimal result still Luis's answer. (example of 100000 records)

```
Ani's: 21
Luis: 4
Jaider's: 15
```

Here my extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectExt<R, T>(this IEnumerable<R> list, params Func<R, T>[] GetValueList)
{
    var result = new List<T>(list.Count() * GetValueList.Length);
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        foreach (var getValue in GetValueList)
        {
            var value = getValue(item);
            result.Add(value);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The usage, will be:

```
var codes = demoList.SelectExt(item => item.Code1, item => item.Code2).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice one.but you might enumerate your list argument twice because of .count()